# Increase bangla font size within php mysql site

Tags: php, mysql, css

I'm creating dynamic site with Php and Mysql. I've both English and Bangla content in my site. But issue is, it's look too much small then English text. So that can't read Bangla content. Is there any way to increase the Bangla font size. I can't increase the Bangla font size. Please see http://www.favoritebd.com then you can understand what i'm asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean that you would like to increase the size of Bangla characters with respect to Latin (English) letters. This is very understandable, since now in my viewing conditions, which are probably rather typical, the Latin letters are readable whereas the Bangla characters, which are much richer in details, are probably less convenient to read.

The reason is that the page sets `font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif` but neither Arial nor Helvetica contains (as far as I know) Bangla characters. This means that they will be taken from a “backup” font, which is typically Vrinda (on Windows; see [list of Windows fonts by language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_fonts)). The Latin letters are still taken from Arial, which is a font with rather different characteristics.

The solution is change the font settings so that you suggest only fonts that contain all the characters used on the page, or at least all normal letters in all languages used. Base on the information at fileformat.info on [font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9b0/fontsupport.htm) and on the fact that Vrinda has support, too, I would suggest

```
font-family: Vrinda, Arial Unicode MS, Likhan, Rupali, SoleimanLipi, Code2000
```

and adding some of the Ekushey fonts there.

Then you can consider whether your font size is suitable, and perhaps increase it or remove the overall `font-size` setting (i.e., let browsers use their defaults).

Related document (mainly on special symbols, but has some applicability to normal text, too): [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jikka K. Korpela, How do i add Ekushey fonts and where i add ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that you can't increase the Bangla font size?  The easiest solution I can think of, if you know that the content is Bangla is to add a CSS tag to any elements with that content, and then a CSS rule for that tag that has `font-size: 1.2em;` or to increase the font size only for that content.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @jmoerdyk. Your idea is OK but i've both english and bangla text combination. So how do i select bangla text? Ex: <div class='box'> There are bangla and english text, so how do i increase bangla font size, In my css it's 14px now for full body  </div>

Answer (score 0):

It works here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StDsA/)

Basically set your ":lang(bangla)" css style to have larger font size.

Comment: That would only address the symptoms, not the real problem (see my answer). Moreover, it would require detailed language markup in HTML: separating between Bangla text and other text. And “bangla” is not a valid language code in HTML and CSS.

Comment: In html lang tag i don't see any bangla attribute, just a see something...ar, be, bg, br...etc. So bg means bangla?

Comment: It's actually whatever you want. It's a key/value pair. You specify lang, then set the tag to whatever you want. It could be bangla, or bg, or whatever you want to put in.